# Ajax Post Call Not Working for On KeyUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying to figure this issue out with no luck. I am doing an ajax post to get a list of courses. There are two ways to get the list. The user can click a search button or press enter. Clicking the search button works and returns the list of courses fine; however, pressing enter does not work. It always returns an error "jqXHR.status = 0 - not connected."

**These are the two events that are both calling PerformSearch().**

**This keyup event does not work.**

```
$('#searchFor').on('keyup', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.which === 13) {
        // $('#SearchCourses').click();
        PerformSearch();
    }
})
```

**The click event works fine.**

```
$('#SearchCourses').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    PerformSearch();
})


   var PerformSearch = function () {
        var searchValue = $('#SearchCourses').val();
        var searchType = $('#searchFor').val();
        var courseObj = {};
        var Course = {};
        Course.searchValue = searchValue;
        Course.searchType = searchType;

        courseObj.data = JSON.stringify({ "courseObj": Course });
        courseObj.contentType = 'application/json';
        courseObj.method = 'post';
        courseObj.url = '/Home/GetCourses';
        courseObj.dataType = 'html';
        PostAPI(courseObj, DisplayCourses); //This is just doing the post nothing interested in the PostAPI.
    };

  var DisplayCourses = function (result) {
        if (!result.Error) {
            $('#CourseList').html(result.data);
        }
    }
```

//The server side code that return the list of courses.

```
 public ActionResult GetCourses(Course courseObj)
  {
    .
    .
    .
    return PartialView("Courses", courses);
 }
```

**The event is submitting the entire page instead of just the course object.**

Comment: Any sample fiddle?

Comment: If you stick that in a form, and use the `submit` event instead, you'll save yourself a lot of grief. Other than that, the issue doesn't seem to be the posted code, they both just call the same function, and that function is not posted, so we have no idea what it does.

Comment: I added another input textbox with the same name and different id. Then, the event starts working for the original textbox. It's not making sense to me right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$('#searchFor').bind('keypress', function (e) {
                    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
                    if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
                        //Do something
                        PerformSearch();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the form submission

```
if (event.which === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   PerformSearch();
}
```